# MySQL convert timestamp and time string to DateTime format

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp, date-arithmetic

In my table have two columns, one as timestamp to save the date and one as time string to save the time with period.
Eg: 
[image]

I want to combine them into one column as DateTime format in the result then order by desc on that column.

Here is the example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25eb21/4

The column name 'Datetime' expected is Datetime or timestamps type, so I can sort correctly on it.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What should the results you look like? Please edit your question to add this important piece of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to convert the values to integers to add them.  MySQL has built-in functions for this purpose:

```
SELECT *,
       addtime(apptDate, str_to_date(apptTime, '%h:%i %p')) as datetime
FROM appt
ORDER BY Datetime DESC;
```

If `apptTime` is just a `time` value (which it should be), then you obviously do not need to convert from a string.  I would usuggest fixing the data model.

Comment: In my MySQL server, the STR_TO_DATE() function always return Null

Comment: @dangquang1020 . . . It certainly seems to work on the data you provided:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7e6df70e0276c92f50571a3c2e18a4b9.

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume that you want to add the duration that is stored as a string in column `apptTime` to timestamp in column `apptDate`.

A typical approach uses `str_to_date()` to turn the string to a `datetime`, then converts the time portion to seconds using `time_to_sec()`, which we can then add to the timestamp using date artihmetics.

So

```
select t.*
    apptdate 
        + interval time_to_sec(str_to_date(appttime, '%h:%i %p')) second 
        as newapptdate
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select addtime(appDate, appTime) from ...
```

Your appDate contains a time, probably because you are applying a timezone.  Either convert your two columns to the timezone your data is supposed to be in with convert_tz(), or extract the date part of it with date(appDate) before you add it.  It wasn't clear which of the columns was a string, but extract() or str_to_date() is the way to parse a text into a date and/or time.